# Assign value to caller variable in extension method in C#

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I am facing a problem with extension method. I made a generic extension method for getting QueryString. I am calling that method with specific type of variable which type of data is coming with QueryString. My extension method is given below.

```
public static class my
{
    public static void GetQueryString<T>(this T caller, string queryString)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[queryString] != null)
        {
            T type = (T)Convert.ChangeType(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[queryString], typeof(T));
            caller = type;
        }
    }

    public static void GetQueryString(this Employee caller)
    {
        caller.ID = 23;
    }
}
```

I wanna get string value from querystring for that I declared a string variable and then call the extension method. I want to get the querystring value in "t1" variable.

```
 string t1 = string.Empty;
 t1.GetQueryString("name");
```

But the value is not coming in caller variable. The same thing is working with extension method which is related with Employee object, but I wanna take value in primitive types. If anyone has idea about it then please share with me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot change the value of `caller` because is passed by val, in c# you cannot pass the `this` parameter of an extension method by ref. Your second method works because you didn't change the value of `caller` obviously.

Comment: I really agree with you that that passed by val is not changed but extension method also extend the primitive type. Then I wanna know that is there any scope to do this. As you saw the above Employee object is assigned the value to ID property.

Comment: Yes but the value of `caller` isn't changed it points the same object. As a side note VB.NET let you pass the parameter by ref.

Comment: Actually My purpose is to know that If employee is calling this function then it assigned value in ID but if I made a int variable and call by this that not assigning any value and both using "this" keyword in extension parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
public static T GetQueryString<T>(this T caller, string queryString)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[queryString] != null)
    {
        T type = (T)Convert.ChangeType(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[queryString], typeof(T));

        return type;
    }
}

string t1 = string.Empty;
t1 = t1.GetQueryString("name"); // return the value and reassign
```

But I didn't tested the `GetQueryString` method.
The only way I can think of is, but without extension method:

```
public static T GetQueryString<T>(ref T caller, string queryString)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[queryString] != null)
    {
        T type = (T)Convert.ChangeType(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[queryString], typeof(T));

        return type;
    }
}

GetQueryString(ref t1, "name");
```

Comment: Dear, I can also return the value of querystring but I don't wanna do this, because for this I have to assign same variable like t1=t1.GetQueryString("name"); and I don't wanna do this.